# redefine array keys php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TotalClicksPerDay] => 5
            [Date] => 2012-11-26
            [weekDay] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TotalClicksPerDay] => 13
            [Date] => 2012-11-27
            [weekDay] => 6
        )

)
```

I want to redefine the keys by using the value [weekday] as the key.

So in the example above, the new array would read like so:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [TotalClicksPerDay] => 5
            [Date] => 2012-11-26
            [weekDay] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [TotalClicksPerDay] => 13
            [Date] => 2012-11-27
            [weekDay] => 6
        )
)
```

Comment: weekdays aren't quite unique values, so be careful not to generate weird bugs.

Comment: What if they are multiple week days ?

Comment: @Baba I am grouping all my days as weekDays in the mysql query.  I needed to know the totalClicks per day. So in a full year, I would need to show the Total clicks for Mondays for the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($old_array as $values) {
    $new_array[$values['weekDay']] = $values;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! this works perfectly. I can only accpet the answer in 12 minutes, but I will then.